# difficulty with a math assignment in python

Tags: python, loops

I am provided with a value N. I am to calculate the sum of all squares up to and including N. In math this is commonly called ∑Ni=0i2. It must be calculated in a loop. I have tried everything I can think of, even break statements, but I haven't been able to get it to work. 
This is the closest I've come

```
Ans = 1
for i in range(N):
  if i == N:
    Ans = Ans*N
print (Ans)
```

I've made sure everything is indented and that my print statement is outside the loop, I think I am using the wrong formula, but I can't think of a better one. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Your program never squares or sums anything...

Comment: Before the loop set a variable `total` to 0. Then in the loop add i * i to this variable at each iteration.

Comment: "∑Ni=0i2" - wat

Answer (score 2):

Try this. You can set the upper value with `num`, and it prints the answer. `sum` acts on an iterable here rather than a list.

```
num=5
print(sum(e**2 for e in range(num+1)))
```